# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.(Spring Security & Angular)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

This is the error I get when i try to login through basic authentication in spring security.
@CrossOrigin() annotation is included in rest controller. But still i get this message.
I've also tried @CrossOrigin(origins = { "localhost:4200"}, allowedHeaders={"Accept"}), still the message is shown whenever i try to login.

Angular method to authenticate:(I'm returning the logged in user id in rest controller)

```
authenticate(username, password) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });

  return this.http.get<number>('http://localhost:8080/hiring-prediction-tool/users/login', {headers})
  .pipe(map(
      userData => {
        console.log(userData, 'userData');
        sessionStorage.setItem('username',username);
        let authString = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);
        sessionStorage.setItem('basicauth', authString);
        return userData;
      }
    )
  ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to solve this is by using a server like nginx or apache to direct the traffic to the frontend or backend portion of the site.

You can also let the backend serve up your angular site. Run `ng build` (I am using the development configuration below) and have the outputPath in your `angular.json` file place the files into the server. e.g.

```
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "extractCss": true,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "watch": true,
          "poll": 1000,
          "outputPath": "../server/target/classes/static"
        }
```

You will need to do a bit of extra configuration to get everything served up but then the entire site would be located at `localhost:8080`.

You can also disable CORS in your spring security configuration with:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().disable();
}
```

Although that is not the best long term solution.